# Entity Framework Package Manager Console question

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have EF 5 and I added the following table and it added successfully as shown in code snippet #1. However, I want the **UserID** to be a foreign key that references the **Users** table and if I did that, then my code would have looked like code snippet# 2. 
Without deleting this new table, can you please tell me how I can now make the UserID to be a foreign key that references Users table. Thank you so much. I'm using **Package Manager Console** to achieve this.

**Code snippet #1**

```
public partial class Initialignorechanges : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Favorite",
            c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                UserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                UserName = c.String(nullable: true, maxLength: 25, unicode: false),
                FavoritedUserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                FavoritedUserName = c.String(nullable: true, maxLength: 25, unicode: false),
                FavoritedDate = c.DateTime(),
                ShowToUser = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                ShowToFavoritedUser = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);                
    }

    public override void Down()
    {            
        DropTable("dbo.Favorite");
    }
}
```

**Code snippet #2:**

```
public partial class Initialignorechanges : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Favorite",
            c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                UserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                UserName = c.String(nullable: true, maxLength: 25, unicode: false),
                FavoritedUserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                FavoritedUserName = c.String(nullable: true, maxLength: 25, unicode: false),
                FavoritedDate = c.DateTime(),
                ShowToUser = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                ShowToFavoritedUser = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserID);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Favorite", new[] { "UserID" });
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Favorite", "UserID", "dbo.Users");
        DropTable("dbo.Favorite");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx). You have there how to make table relationships. One-To-One, One-To-Many, Many-To-Many. After you make the models add a new migration, update db and EF will take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Code-Based Migration in Entity Framework 6](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx).

> Now, you have to create a migration class using the Add-Migration
>   command with the name of your migration class, as shown below.

[image]

> After creating a migration file using the add-migration command, you
>   have to update the database. Execute the Update-Database command to
>   create or modify a database schema. Use the –verbose option to view
>   the SQL statements being applied to the target database.

[image]

> At this point, the database will be created or updated. Now, whenever
>   you change the domain classes, execute Add-Migration with the name
>   parameter to create a new migration file and then execute the
>   Update-Database command to apply the changes to the database schema.